# How to have a Firefox Devtools inspector like feature for Firefox addons?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools, inspect, web-inspector

For ex: I want to see which parts of the html code correspond to a specific element of a website, I would right-click on the element and open `inspect element` and devtools would show me the corresponding code highlighted. How do I achieve a similar result for Firefox addons because when I right click on the extension there's no such option of `inspect element`.

I have also tried to use the `inspect` option which we get by temporarily loading an addon but still it doesn't show us/highlight which parts of the extension the corresponding html file refer to. 
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

In current versions of Firefox, inspecting and debugging add-ons works by opening the Add-ons Manager, clicking the gear icon at the top and choosing *Debug Add-ons* or by going to about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox.

In there you'll get a list of all installed add-ons. And you can debug them by clicking on the *Inspect* button besides them.

[image: about:debugging page listing installed add-ons with Inspect button highlighted]

This opens up a new DevTools window just for that specific add-on. So you can inspect and debug them.

[image: DevTools window for add-on debugging]

In older versions of Firefox, debugging add-ons is a bit more cumbersome.
Depending on the type of extension, it is possible to inspect their contents using the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox).

This feature first needs to be enabled by switching to the DevTools' [Settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings) panel and enabling the two options *Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes* and *Enable remote debugging*.

Once they are enabled, you can open the Browser Toolbox via the Firefox Menu > *Web Developer* > *Browser Toolbox* or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac.

This toolbox has an Inspector like the normal DevTools, which allows you to inspect the browser chrome.

Having said that, the Inspector obviously can't inspect documents placed in nested `<browser>` elements, which is the case for extensions to the DevTools themselves, for example.